# Как я могу заставить идти стрелки в часах?

Tags: javascript, svg

Когда вы открываете страницу, секундная стрелка направлена вверх, и только после второго показа, начинает идти. Мне нужно запустить их без этой секунды, но я не могу изменить `setInterval(1000)`, и у меня нет идей о том, как это исправить. Помогите, пожалуйста. `setInterval (moveArrows, 1000)` находится в конце кода.

```
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
console.log(svg);
const svg_xnls = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
//если не найдет аттрибутов width || height, то вернет null
const width = parseFloat(svg.getAttributeNS(null, 'width'));
const height = parseFloat(svg.getAttributeNS(null, 'height'));
// радиус часиков (большого желтого круга)
const clockRadius = width / 2;
// радиус кружочков с цифрами часов времени
const radius = 0.8 * clockRadius;

//создаю переменные половин ширины и высоты
let widthHalf = width / 2;
let heightHalf = height / 2;

// создаю функцию желтого круга
function drawClockBody(clock) {

    // создаю круг
    let clockBodyStyle = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'circle');

    // задаю атрибуты/стили (с - center)
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', widthHalf);
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', heightHalf);
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', widthHalf);
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#fcca66');
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'none');

    //рисую круг в HTML
    svg.appendChild(clockBodyStyle);
}

drawClockBody();

// можно было сделать двумя функциями
// создаю функцию для кружочков с цифрами
function drawHours(hour, hourValue) {

    // градус угла
    const angel = 30;

    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

        // рисую круг
        let hourCircle = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'circle');
        svg.appendChild(hourCircle);

        // раставляю кружочки по кругу
        let angelRadian = (angel * i * Math.PI) / 180;

        //считаю центр кружочка относительно тела часов
        let hourCenterX = clockRadius + radius * Math.sin(angelRadian);
        let hourCenterY = clockRadius - radius * Math.cos(angelRadian);

        // задаю атрибуты/стили
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', hourCenterX);
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', hourCenterY);
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 40);
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#48b382');
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'none');

        // cоздаю текс
        let text = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'text');
        svg.appendChild(text);
        // контент текста равен i
        text.textContent = i;
        // задаю атрибуты/стили
        text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', hourCenterX);
        text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', hourCenterY + 13);
        text.style.width = '80';
        text.style.height = '80';
        text.style.fontSize = '40';
        text.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        text.style.textAnchor = 'middle';
    }
}
drawHours();

// создаю функцию стрелок
function drawArrows(hour_arrow, minute_arrow, second_aqrrow) {

    // создаю стрелку часов
    const hourArrow = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'line');

    // задаю атрибуты/стили
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', widthHalf);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', widthHalf);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', widthHalf);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 100);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#000000');
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 6);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'hours');
    // рисую стрелку
    svg.appendChild(hourArrow);

    // создаю стрелку часов
    const minuteArrow = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'line');
    // задаю атрибуты/стили
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', widthHalf);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', widthHalf);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', widthHalf);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 60);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#0000ff');
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 4);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'minutes');
    // рисую стрелку
    svg.appendChild(minuteArrow);

    // создаю стрелку часов
    const secondArrow = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'line');
    // задаю атрибуты/стили
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', widthHalf);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', widthHalf);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', widthHalf);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 40);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#ff2000');
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 2);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'seconds');
    // рисую стрелку
    svg.appendChild(secondArrow);
}
drawArrows();

// создаю элемент текста
const textTime = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'text');
svg.appendChild(textTime);
// задаю стили
textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 300);
textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 200);
textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'text-time');
textTime.style.fontSize = '2rem';
textTime.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
textTime.style.textAnchor = 'middle';

window.onload = function operation() {


    function moveArrows() {

        const now = new Date();
        let seconds = now.getSeconds() * 6;
        // console.log(seconds);
        let minutes = now.getMinutes() * 6;
        // console.log(minutes);
        // задаю так часы, чтобы они не перескакивали с часа на час, а плавно шли от часа к часу
        let hours = (now.getHours() + now.getMinutes() / 60 + now.getSeconds() * 3600) * 30;

        // беру стрелки по Id, чтоб потом передать им анимацию
        let hoursStyle = document.getElementById('hours');
        let minutesStyle = document.getElementById('minutes');
        let secondsStyle = document.getElementById('seconds');
        // задаю анимацию
        secondsStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + seconds + ' 300 300)');
        minutesStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + minutes + ' 300 300)');
        hoursStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + hours + ' 300 300)');

        // создаю функцию в которой буду показывать время в виде циферок
        function showTime(time) {
            // делаю проверку для красоты, (const textHour = now.getHours() - работает одинаково)
            const textHour = (now.getHours() < 10) ? ('0' + now.getHours()) : (now.getHours());
            const textMinutes = (now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ('0' + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes());
            const textSeconds = (now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ('0' + now.getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds());

            // беру по id мой текст и вставляю туда время
            document.getElementById("text-time").textContent = textHour + ':' + textMinutes + ':' + textSeconds;
        }
        showTime();

    }


    setInterval(moveArrows, 1000);
};
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can i make arrows go in clock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60988721/7394871) от участника  [@10100011001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12799277/10100011001).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60988721/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На основе [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60991291/7394871) от [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).
Чуть подправил, добавил немного фишек, контур стрелки при чётных наведениях, подсветка, озвучка, пару овалов с градиентом ну и т.п. 
В общем мелочи, но приятно было повозиться )
Спасибо за интересную задачу.

```js
    const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
    //console.log(svg);
    const svg_xnls = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    //если не найдет аттрибутов width || height, то вернет null
    const width = parseFloat(svg.getAttributeNS(null, 'width'));
    const height = parseFloat(svg.getAttributeNS(null, 'height'));
    // радиус часиков (большого желтого круга)
    const clockRadius = width / 2;
    // радиус кружочков с цифрами часов времени
    const radius = 0.8 * clockRadius;

    //создаю переменные половин ширины и высоты
    let widthHalf = width / 2;
    let heightHalf = height / 2;

    // создаю функцию желтого круга
    function drawClockBody(clock) {

        // создаю круг
        let clockBodyStyle = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'circle');

        // задаю атрибуты/стили (с - center)
        clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', widthHalf);
        clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', heightHalf);
        clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', widthHalf);
        clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#413f3f');
        clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'gold');
        clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '2%');

        //рисую круг в HTML
        svg.appendChild(clockBodyStyle);

    }

    drawClockBody();

    //Добавим кнопку

    let minsec = 0;
    function addButton() {
        let mmain = document.createElement('div');
        mmain.style.width = '100%';
        let but = document.createElement('button');
        but.id = 'butt';
        but.innerText = 'Озвучить секунды';
        but.style.marginLeft = '5px';
        but.style.marginTop = '20px';
        but.style.height = '35px';
        but.style.backgroundColor = 'gold';
        but.style.width = '150px';
        but.style.fontSize = '12';
        but.style.fontWeight = '600';
        but.style.border = '4px double black';
        mmain.appendChild(but);
        let but1 = document.createElement('button');
        but1.id = 'butt1';
        but1.innerText = 'Точное время';
        but1.style.height = '35px';
        but1.style.width = '150px';
        but1.style.backgroundColor = 'gold';
        but1.style.fontSize = '12';
        but1.style.fontWeight = '600';
        but1.style.border = '4px double black';
        mmain.appendChild(but1);
        document.body.appendChild(mmain);

        but.onclick = function () {
            minsec = 0;
        };
        but1.onclick = function () {
            let tttime = new Date();
            var HmmTime = function(number, titles) {
                var  cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
                return titles[
                    (number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20)
                        ?
                        2
                        :
                        cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]
                    ];
            };
            tttime = 'Точное время '+tttime.getHours()+' '+HmmTime(tttime.getHours(), ['час', 'часа', 'часов'])+' '+tttime.getMinutes()+ ' ' +HmmTime(tttime.getMinutes(), ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут'])+' и '+tttime.getSeconds()+' '+HmmTime(tttime.getSeconds(), ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']);
            minsec = 1;
            var lang = "ru-RU";

            var synth = window.speechSynthesis,
                voice = '',
                supportedVoices = [];

            if (0 === supportedVoices.length) {
                var voices = synth.getVoices();
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
                if (lang == voices[i].lang) {
                    voice = voices[i];
                }
            }
            var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(tttime);
            utterThis.voice = voice;
            synth.speak(utterThis);
        }
    }
    addButton();

    // можно было сделать двумя функциями
    // создаю функцию для кружочков с цифрами
    function drawHours(hour, hourValue) {

        // градус угла
        const angel = 30;

        for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

            // рисую круг
            let hourCircle = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'circle');
            svg.appendChild(hourCircle);

            // раставляю кружочки по кругу
            let angelRadian = (angel * i * Math.PI) / 180;

            //считаю центр кружочка относительно тела часов
            let hourCenterX = clockRadius + radius * Math.sin(angelRadian);
            let hourCenterY = clockRadius - radius * Math.cos(angelRadian);

            // задаю атрибуты/стили
            hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', hourCenterX);
            hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', hourCenterY);
            hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 21);
            hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#74797a');
            hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'gold');
            hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '1px');
            hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'name', 'bz');

            // cоздаю текс
            let text = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'text');
            svg.appendChild(text);
            // контент текста равен i
            text.textContent = i;
            // задаю атрибуты/стили
            text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', hourCenterX);
            text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', hourCenterY + 13);
            text.style.width = '80';
            text.style.height = '80';
            text.style.fontSize = '40';
            text.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
            text.style.textAnchor = 'middle';
        }
    }
    drawHours();

    // создаю функцию стрелок
    function drawArrows(hour_arrow, minute_arrow, second_aqrrow) {

        // создаю стрелку часов
        const hourArrow = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'line');

        // задаю атрибуты/стили
        hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', widthHalf);
        hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', widthHalf);
        hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', widthHalf);
        hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 100);
        hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#000000');
        hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
        hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 6);
        hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'hours');
        // рисую стрелку
        svg.appendChild(hourArrow);

        // создаю стрелку часов
        const minuteArrow = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'line');
        // задаю атрибуты/стили
        minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', widthHalf);
        minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', widthHalf);
        minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', widthHalf);
        minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 60);
        minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#0000ff');
        minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
        minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 4);
        minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'minutes');
        // рисую стрелку
        svg.appendChild(minuteArrow);

        // создаю стрелку часов
        const secondArrow = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'line');
        // задаю атрибуты/стили
        secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', widthHalf);
        secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', widthHalf);
        secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', widthHalf);
        secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 40);
        secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#ff2000');
        secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
        secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 2);
        secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'seconds');
        // рисую стрелку
        svg.appendChild(secondArrow);
    }

    function moveArrows() {

        const now = new Date();
        let seconds = now.getSeconds() * 6;
        // console.log(seconds);
        let minutes = now.getMinutes() * 6;
        // console.log(minutes);
        // задаю так часы, чтобы они не перескакивали с часа на час, а плавно шли от часа к часу
        let hours = (now.getHours() + now.getMinutes() / 60 + now.getSeconds() * 3600) * 30;


        // беру стрелки по Id, чтоб потом передать им анимацию
        let hoursStyle = document.getElementById('hours');
        let minutesStyle = document.getElementById('minutes');
        let secondsStyle = document.getElementById('seconds');
        // задаю анимацию
        secondsStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + seconds + ' ' + widthHalf + ' ' + heightHalf + ')');
        minutesStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + minutes + ' ' + widthHalf + ' ' + heightHalf + ')');
        hoursStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + hours + ' ' + widthHalf + ' ' + heightHalf + ')');


        let subsec = Number.isInteger(seconds/5); // Это если надо оставлять подсвеченным элемент до следующего числа.
        // немного посмеяться )))
        let z = document.getElementsByName('bz');
        let valz = 0; // Пурум Пум Пум
        let raddd = secondsStyle.getAttributeNS(null, 'transform');
        let raddd1 = raddd.split('(')[1].split(' ')[0]; // Получим ротацию.
        for(let iz=0;iz<z.length;iz++){
            valz += 30; // Шаг 30 так как 460 же
            if(raddd1 == valz){
                z[iz].setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#f7feff');
            } else {
                z[iz].setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#74797a');
            }
            if (raddd1 == 0){
                z[iz].setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#8088ff');
            }
        }

        // создаю функцию в которой буду показывать время в виде циферок

        // Блин это круто прям..... (коммент от Дениса)
        function showTime(time) {
            // делаю проверку для красоты, (const textHour = now.getHours() - работает одинаково)
            const textHour = (now.getHours() < 10) ? ('0' + now.getHours()) : (now.getHours());
            const textMinutes = (now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ('0' + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes());
            const textSeconds = (now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ('0' + now.getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds());

            // беру по id мой текст и вставляю туда время
            document.getElementById("text-time").textContent = textHour + ':' + textMinutes + ':' + textSeconds;
        }
        showTime();
        DinDon();
    }


    function sayTime(haha) {
        speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(haha));
    }
    
    function DinDon() {
        //let ttime = new Date().getMinutes();
        ttime = new Date().getSeconds();
        let submin = Number.isInteger(ttime/5);

        let haha;
        if (ttime/5 == 0){ // Можно было сделать функцией озвучки, но она работает по исключительно по нажатию, точнее активации. А нам надо отслеживать и триггер. Можно сделать, да и стрелку на триггер true от isInteger, но время уже... и лениво )))
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Прошла минута дорогие друзья';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 1){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Пять секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 2){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Десять секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 3){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Пятнадцать секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 4){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Двадцать секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 5){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Двадцать пять секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 6){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Тридцать секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 7){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Тридать пять секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 8){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Сорок секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 9){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Сорок пять секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 10){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Пятьдесят секунд';
        } else if(ttime/5 == 11){
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '5';
            haha = 'Пятьдесят пять секунд';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('seconds').style.strokeWidth = '2';
        }
        if(submin == true){
            if (minsec != 1) {
                sayTime(haha);
            }
        }
    }


    // Ради интереса добавить градиент
    const grad = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'linearGradient');
    grad.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'grad');
    const stop1 = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'stop');
    stop1.setAttributeNS(null, 'offset', '0%');
    stop1.setAttributeNS(null, 'stop-color', 'white');
    const stop2 = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'stop');
    stop2.setAttributeNS(null, 'offset', '100%');
    stop2.setAttributeNS(null, 'stop-color', 'grey');

    grad.appendChild(stop1);
    grad.appendChild(stop2);
    svg.appendChild(grad);

    // Создаём овал

    const bord = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'rect');
    svg.appendChild(bord);
    bord.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'url(#grad)');
    bord.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '80');
    bord.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '165');
    bord.setAttributeNS(null, 'rx', '220');
    bord.setAttributeNS(null, 'ry', '230');
    bord.style.width = '142px';
    bord.style.height = '50px';
    bord.style.strokeWidth = '4';
    // создаю элемент текста
    const textTime = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'text');
    svg.appendChild(textTime);
    // задаю стили
    textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 150);
    textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 200);
    textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'text-time');
    textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'black');
    textTime.style.fontSize = '2rem';
    textTime.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    textTime.style.textAnchor = 'middle';


    drawArrows();
    moveArrows();

    window.onload = function operation() {
        setInterval(moveArrows, 1000);
    };
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="300" height="300">
</svg>
```

Comment: Отлично! Мне очень понравилось. Проснусь, посмотрю подробней Ваш код. Конечно особенно восхищает озвучка, подсветка!!! Великолепно

Comment: я раньше не видел твоих ответов по векторной графике ...+ от  меня

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Я получил огромное удовольствие работая над этой задачей. Даже в некоторых моментах похохотал ночью в глубокой тишине ))) Сам бы полностью всё я наврятли сделал, так что спасибо Вам большое за интересную задачу. Было приятно поделать ) Я там ещё подправлю чуть-чуть, то что ночью не доделал, чтобы было идеально, без вариативности а по функциям )

Comment: @MaximLensky Ну я вот смотрю всё на ваши работы. Что Ваши, Что Alexandr_TT, что StrangerInTheQ, что Sevastopol`. И вообще появляются мысли, а тем ли я вообще занимаюсь? ))) Графика это очень интересно, правда у меня пока очень мало знаний в этой сфере. Могу только восхищаться вашими работами. Причём что ни ответ - то произведение искусства у каждого )

Answer (score 4):

Просто вызовите функцию `moveArrows()` во время инициализации.

```
drawArrows();
moveArrows();
```

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
//console.log(svg);
const svg_xnls = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
//если не найдет аттрибутов width || height, то вернет null
const width = parseFloat(svg.getAttributeNS(null, 'width'));
const height = parseFloat(svg.getAttributeNS(null, 'height'));
// радиус часиков (большого желтого круга)
const clockRadius = width / 2;
// радиус кружочков с цифрами часов времени
const radius = 0.8 * clockRadius;

//создаю переменные половин ширины и высоты
let widthHalf = width / 2;
let heightHalf = height / 2;

// создаю функцию желтого круга
function drawClockBody(clock) {

    // создаю круг
    let clockBodyStyle = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'circle');

    // задаю атрибуты/стили (с - center)
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', widthHalf);
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', heightHalf);
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', widthHalf);
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#fcca66');
    clockBodyStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'none');

    //рисую круг в HTML
    svg.appendChild(clockBodyStyle);
}

drawClockBody();

// можно было сделать двумя функциями
// создаю функцию для кружочков с цифрами
function drawHours(hour, hourValue) {

    // градус угла
    const angel = 30;

    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

        // рисую круг
        let hourCircle = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'circle');
        svg.appendChild(hourCircle);

        // раставляю кружочки по кругу
        let angelRadian = (angel * i * Math.PI) / 180;

        //считаю центр кружочка относительно тела часов
        let hourCenterX = clockRadius + radius * Math.sin(angelRadian);
        let hourCenterY = clockRadius - radius * Math.cos(angelRadian);

        // задаю атрибуты/стили
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', hourCenterX);
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', hourCenterY);
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 40);
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#48b382');
        hourCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'none');

        // cоздаю текс
        let text = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'text');
        svg.appendChild(text);
        // контент текста равен i
        text.textContent = i;
        // задаю атрибуты/стили
        text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', hourCenterX);
        text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', hourCenterY + 13);
        text.style.width = '80';
        text.style.height = '80';
        text.style.fontSize = '40';
        text.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        text.style.textAnchor = 'middle';
    }
}
drawHours();

// создаю функцию стрелок
function drawArrows(hour_arrow, minute_arrow, second_aqrrow) {

    // создаю стрелку часов
    const hourArrow = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'line');

    // задаю атрибуты/стили
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', widthHalf);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', widthHalf);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', widthHalf);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 100);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#000000');
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 6);
    hourArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'hours');
    // рисую стрелку
    svg.appendChild(hourArrow);

    // создаю стрелку часов
    const minuteArrow = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'line');
    // задаю атрибуты/стили
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', widthHalf);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', widthHalf);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', widthHalf);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 60);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#0000ff');
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 4);
    minuteArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'minutes');
    // рисую стрелку
    svg.appendChild(minuteArrow);

    // создаю стрелку часов
    const secondArrow = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'line');
    // задаю атрибуты/стили
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', widthHalf);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', widthHalf);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', widthHalf);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 40);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#ff2000');
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linecap', 'round');
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 2);
    secondArrow.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'seconds');
    // рисую стрелку
    svg.appendChild(secondArrow);
}

function moveArrows() {

    const now = new Date();
    let seconds = now.getSeconds() * 6;
    // console.log(seconds);
    let minutes = now.getMinutes() * 6;
    // console.log(minutes);
    // задаю так часы, чтобы они не перескакивали с часа на час, а плавно шли от часа к часу
    let hours = (now.getHours() + now.getMinutes() / 60 + now.getSeconds() * 3600) * 30;

    // беру стрелки по Id, чтоб потом передать им анимацию
    let hoursStyle = document.getElementById('hours');
    let minutesStyle = document.getElementById('minutes');
    let secondsStyle = document.getElementById('seconds');
    // задаю анимацию
    secondsStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + seconds + ' ' + widthHalf + ' ' + heightHalf + ')');
    minutesStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + minutes + ' ' + widthHalf + ' ' + heightHalf + ')');
    hoursStyle.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + hours + ' ' + widthHalf + ' ' + heightHalf + ')');

    // создаю функцию в которой буду показывать время в виде циферок
    function showTime(time) {
        // делаю проверку для красоты, (const textHour = now.getHours() - работает одинаково)
        const textHour = (now.getHours() < 10) ? ('0' + now.getHours()) : (now.getHours());
        const textMinutes = (now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ('0' + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes());
        const textSeconds = (now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ('0' + now.getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds());

        // беру по id мой текст и вставляю туда время
        document.getElementById("text-time").textContent = textHour + ':' + textMinutes + ':' + textSeconds;
    }
    showTime();
}

// создаю элемент текста
const textTime = document.createElementNS(svg_xnls, 'text');
svg.appendChild(textTime);
// задаю стили
textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 300);
textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 200);
textTime.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'text-time');
textTime.style.fontSize = '2rem';
textTime.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
textTime.style.textAnchor = 'middle';

drawArrows();
moveArrows();

window.onload = function operation() {
    setInterval(moveArrows, 1000);
};
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="300" height="300">
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How can i make arrows go in clock?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60991291/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>